# Firebase onDisconnect doesn't work until the player reconnects the network. - Java

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm making a test game, I need to add a number to a specific path in the Firebase database when a player loses connection. This works, but only when the player reconnects, not immediately after being disconnected.

How can I solve it?

---

my Code:

```
DatabaseReference leaveRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("rooms/" + roomName + "/playersLeave");
leaveRef.onDisconnect().setValue(1);
```

Comment: Answer on what is likely happening is below. If you want advice on how to progress with your use-case, tell us more about what you're trying to accomplish as right now it's pretty much a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 2):

An `onDisconnect` handler that you register runs on the server when it detects that the client has disconnected. There are two ways that this may happen:

- Either the client cleanly disconnect, announcing that it will disconnect. In this scenario the `onDisconnect` handlers for that client run immediately. An example of this case is when you call `goOffline()`.
- Or the client experiences a dirty disconnect, in which case the server detects that the client is gone when the socket times out - which may take up to a few minutes. An example of this is when you app crashes.

It sounds like you're experiencing a dirty disconnect, in which case there's nothing you can do to make the server detect it faster.